# Nginx config invalid parameter even though it is in documentation

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I am tryin to run nginx latest version with the following configuration, but I get `nginx: [emerg] invalid parameter "route=bloomberg" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:13`

```
docker run --rm -ti -v root_to_local_nginx_directory:/etc/nginx:ro -p 3080:80  --name=mynginx --entrypoint nginx  nginx
```

```
    # nginx.conf file inside root_to_local_nginx_directory
    http {
        map $cookie_route $route_from_cookie {
            ~.(?P<version>w+)$ $route;
        }

        split_clients "${remote_addr}" $random_route {
            50%     server bloomberg.com route=bloomberg;
            *       server yahoo.com route=yahoo;
        }

        upstream backend {
            zone backend 64k;
            server bloomberg.com route=bloomberg;
            server yahoo.com route=yahoo;

            sticky route $route_from_cookie $randomroute;
        }

        server {
            # ...
            listen 80;
            location / {
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_pass http://backend;
            }
        }
    }
```

Why is this? According to the documentation this should be correct http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#upstream.

Answer (score 7):

The `route=string` parameter of the `server` directive within the `upstream` context is considered to be an enterprise-grade feature, and is thus only available through the commercial subscription, in NGINX Plus, not in OSS NGINX.  (If you look closer into the documentation, you'll notice it's grouped together with the other parameters under a separate *"available as part of our commercial subscription"* subsection.)

Additionally, you're also trying to use some similar "server" parameters within the `split_clients` context as if they were actual directives interpreted by nginx, even though everything is supposed to be string literals in that context; it's unclear whether or not that part is responsible for any errors, but even if not, it's a bad style to introduce such confusion into your configuration.

References:

- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#server
- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_split_clients_module.html#split_clients
- https://www.nginx.com/products/nginx/

Comment: thank you cnst, do you think there is a different way to achieve what I need without using the enterprise version?

Comment: @Ryan what are your requirements?  The original question only mentions what you've tried that didn't work, it doesn't list any requirements that you have for the ideal or acceptable configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are seeing the error is because the split_clients module does not support the route parameter. Alternatively, you can do something along the lines:

```
upstream bloomberg {
    server bloomberg.com route=bloomberg;
}

upstream yahoo {
    server yahoo.com route=yahoo;
}

split_clients "${remote_addr}" $random_route {
    50%     bloomberg;
    *       yahoo;
}
```

Comment: the problem is not in split_clients, the problem is on line ```server bloomberg.com route=bloomberg;```